# In Drupal 7 theme, drush doesn't work

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drush

I need to fix bugs in styles on the site, built on Drupal 7. But when I changed some lines in styles, nothing changed in the browser. When I ran     "drush cc all", I saw in my terminal next (full log contains more than 45k simbols):

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;fr_bote.watchdog&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7, :db_insert_placeholder_8, :db_insert_placeholder_9); Array
```

I have no idea how to fix it, please help me! Thanks for advance!

**Edit

```
drush status

Drupal version                  :  7.34                          
Site URI                        :  http://default                
Database driver                 :  mysql                         
Database hostname               :  localhost                     
Database username               :  admin                         
Database name                   :  fr_bote                       
Database                        :  Connected                     
Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                    
Drupal user                     :  Guest                         
Default theme                   :  bote                          
Administration theme            :  shiny                         
PHP configuration               :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini         
Drush version                   :  5.0-dev                       
Drush configuration             :                                
Drupal root                     :  /var/www/my-website 
Site path                       :  sites/default                 
File directory path             :  sites/default/files           
Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a solution! the problem was in the settings database. in file `php.ini` changed fields `max_execution_time`, and `upload_max_filesize` at large values, delete the old tables, again made export - import tables and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

The message is pretty clear:

The Table `fr_bote.watchdog` is missing in your DB. You have to create it.

Comment: **fr_bote**  is the name of my DB, which contains all the tables for the site.

Comment: @IgorIvancha Can you verify if the table `watchdog` is in the DB?

Comment: Of course, such a table is not! how do I create this table

Comment: This table will be created during installation. Did you run the install.php?
Furthermore: Drush 5 is quite outdated, Drush-6 is current stable and drush-7 is getting ready (just in time for Drupal 8). You might want to upgrade?

Comment: yes, of course! i ran install.php.  you think, i need to upgrade my drush?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose Drush doesn't find your database. You should call it using

```
drush -r /path/to/drupal -l your.website.url
```

so that drush finds your installation directory as well as the correct sites/folder, where the `settings.php` for this site is located.
Maybe to uses `sites/default/settings.php` as a fallback and gets pointed to an empty database?

The best way to use drush is to getting used to site aliases (e.g. start at https://duckduckgo.com/?q=drush+site-aliases). A site alias defines the root path as well as the base.url of a drupal installation. You can even define aliases to remote drupal installations. Drush connects them via ssh - no need to leave your local shell.

Comment: The argument "-l" provides the base URL of your website. Thus if the URL in your webbrowser is "http://test.example.net", then use `drush -r /var/www/mysite -l test.example.net`.
Execute the drush command "status" by running `drush -r /var/www/mysite -l test.example.net status` to see, if your drush finds the correct pathes and database.

Comment: Execute a drush command. Run `drush help [command]` to view command-specific help.  Run `drush topic` to read even more documentation.

Comment: What do you want to say?

Comment: What is the URL when you call the website from your browser? Drush detects http://default, and that's not the intended URL I guess. I proposed the drush upgrade, as in every major drush release there are also bugs fixed and workflows improved. So an drush upgrade is a good choice, but not the solution to your problem.

Comment: localhost/my-website and my-website.dev on virtualhost. upgrading for drush nothing changed

Comment: You allways need to specify the drush arguments "-r ..." and "-l ..." or use drush site aliases. As long as the output of `drush -r ... -l ... status` (and NOT `drush status` without additional arguments!) prints `Site URI:  http://default`, you do not call drush with the context information it needs. There should be printed `Site URI: http://my-website.dev` or something similar.